# How to remap F16 to F19 on macOS?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, functions

So far I managed to remap <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F15</kbd>, but I can't remap <kbd>F16</kbd> to <kbd>F19</kbd>.

When I am in insert mode, nothing happens.

What is weird is that in the terminal, I can see something is intercepted, for example, if I type for <kbd>F16</kbd> I get the output:

```
[17~
```

So, is it possible to handle those keys with Neovim as the shell seems to be able to intercept them?

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). Could you tell us what you tried and how it fails? Can you tell us the result of Ctrl-v F16 in insert mode?

Comment: `Ctrl-v F16` does not output anything, while `Ctrl-v F15` outputs `<F15>`

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is that I have deactivated the special F keys for macOS, to have the standard keys, so F1 opens the help in Neovim and I don't have to press the <kbd>fn</kbd> which is far better.

Then I remapped <kbd>F16</kbd> to <kbd>F19</kbd> on macOS using [BetterTouchTool](https://www.folivora.ai/).

[image]

By doing this, I have the best of both worlds.
I don't use the mac special keys so much, so there is no problem with that.